# Ho to download file in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]

If you have an endpoint which return a file (response). You can download in this way:

```
const newBlob = new Blob([response], { type: "text/csv" })
const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
const link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = data;
link.download = fileName; //set a name for file
link.click();
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this because it is not a question

Answer (score 2):

To download a file in Angular, you can use the following code:

```js
const newBlob = new Blob([response], { type: "text/csv" });
const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
const link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = data;
link.download = fileName; // set a name for the file
link.click();
```

This code creates a new Blob object with the response data and specifies the MIME type of the file. Then, it creates a URL for the Blob object using `window.URL.createObjectURL()`. Next, it creates an `<a>` element, sets the `href` attribute to the URL, and the `download` attribute to the desired file name. Finally, it triggers a click event on the `<a>` element to initiate the file download.

Answer (score 0):

It is straightforward to download a file in `Angular`. We can download a file using the **HTML5** `download` attribute.

```html
    <!--angular-->
    <a 
     href="FilePath.csv"
    class="btn"
    target="_blank"
    download="FileName.csv"
    >
    Download Now
    </a>
```

First, we will create a `assets` folder in the `src` folder, and we will store the file we want to download in the assets folder.

We will add the following code in `app.component.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using msSaveBlob function first and if that does not work then the option is to create a element on the fly, but remember to remove it at the end.

```
public saveFile(blob: Blob, filename: string) {
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob);
    } else {
        const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL( blob);
        const aElement = document.createElement('a');
        aElement.href = blobUrl;
        aElement.download = filename;
        aElement.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(aElement);
        aElement.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
        aElement.remove();    
    }
}
```